# PHP download multiple files as zip error

Tags: php, zip

I tried to make an download button to zip my files. When I set multiple files in the array it gives the error [image]

When I hardcode "files/path/to/8717953176714.jpg" it works.

Here is my code:

```html
<?php

//print_r($_POST["foto"]);

$files = array($_POST["foto"]);
$random = rand(1000000000, 9999999999);
$zipname = 'file'.$random.'.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    $zip->addFile($file);
}

$zip->close();

$filename = $zipname;

 header('Content-type: application/zip');
 header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename . '"');
 header('Content-length: ' . filesize($filename));  
 readfile($filename);
 $file = fopen('iplog.txt', 'a', 1);
 $ipz = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
 $text = "$ipz\n";
 fwrite($file, $text);
 fclose($file); 

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was. I made an array into an array. So it didn't get the good path.

```html
$files = $_POST["foto"];
```

instead of

```html
$files = array($_POST["foto"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this change :

```
$zipname =getcwd()'/file'.$random.'.zip';
```

Comment: echo $zipname; check if path is ok an script is allowed to write there